# Using Angular 2 Can Activate; TS is fine but I'm getting an error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm new to Angular 2, trying to protect routes in a new app. The thing to use would seem to be Can Activate, but even using the simplest example of can activate seems to break angular. I get the following error:

```
ZoneAwareError message:
"Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
at NoProviderError.set [as stack] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6147:61)
at assignAll (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:98482:29)
at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:98553:16)
at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6109:16)
at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58855:16)
at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58904:16)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80617:19)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80654:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80604:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80366:21)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59758:52)
at PreActivation.getToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24841:25)
at MapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24737:48)
at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11337:35)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6655:18)
```

My code is the following.

Can activate:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Routing Module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ThoughtListComponent } from './thoughts/thought-list.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

import { CanActivateAuthGuard } from './can-activate.service';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'thoughtList' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'thoughtList',
      component: ThoughtListComponent,
      canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard]
    }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

export const routableComponents = [
    ThoughtListComponent,
    LoginComponent
];
```

Since I'm using TypeScript, I know that canActivate should be able to return a simple boolean... so I'm not sure why this is breaking. The actual stack trace is all in the vendor code, with no references to my code.

I saw from other posts that the wrong version of zone (0.7.3) can cause an error, but I've tried versions that should work (0.7.2 & 0.7.4). The rest of the app was built off of angular-cli.

I also note that my code works fine when I just comment out the canActivate property of the route... so something particular to canActivate is breaking.

Comment: Have you added CanActivateAuthGuard to the providers of your module?

Comment: Seems the declaration of provider is missing for route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `CanActivateAuthGuard` to your module's providers should fix this error.